# How do I set up Eclipse to run php files on my localhost using XAMPP?

Tags: php, eclipse, xampp

I am using Eclipse MARS edition and getting my feet wet with php. I want to know how to configure eclipse so that when I run the php file it will open it in http://localhost. I have XAMPP already installed and it is working. How do I do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Check the StackOverflow's help on asking questions first, please. Focus on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but also other [help topics](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) would be useful.

Comment: Anyway don't try to set up Eclipse that way. Just open the browser and manually navigate to proper URL. Directly execute scripts only if you need to run them in a console.

Answer (score 1):

1-stop your apache server
2-Change c:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf :

> ```
>      DocumentRoot "xxxxxxxxx" 
>      <Directory "xxxxxxxxx">
> ```

instead of xxxxxxxxx use your workspace that eclipse now use.
3-start your apache 
4-Set runconfiguration
5-Add PHP Web Application
6-Configure your server :

> ```
>     Server Name: http://localhost/yourworkspace
>     Base URL : http://localhost
>     Document Root: yourworkspace on your file system
> ```

7-Path Mapping:

> Path on server : /   And   Path in workspace : /yourworkspace

8-Finish ,Run and Enjoy :)